# How to create event in AWS event bridge Scheduler using dotnet core?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, .net-core, events

I have to schedule event at a specific time, i am using aws-eventbridge-scheduler for that purpose, there is nugget package in Amazon.Scheduler which provides sdk for dealing with scheduler event but there is noo proper example around this if anyone know how to do it please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A CreateScheduleAsync operation would look something like this:

```
var scheduleResult = await scheduler.CreateScheduleAsync(new CreateScheduleRequest
    {
        Name = "test schedule",
        ScheduleExpression = "at(yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss)",  // for a one-time schedule.
        ScheduleExpressionTimezone = "America/Los_Angeles", // specify the timezone
        State = ScheduleState.ENABLED,
        FlexibleTimeWindow = new FlexibleTimeWindow{Mode = FlexibleTimeWindowMode.OFF},
        Target = new Target
        {
            Arn = "ARN of the target, such as a Queue",
            RoleArn = "ARN of the IAM role to use for the target",
            Input = "Test payload here"
        }
    });
```

Your parameters may vary, but there is a good [guide on the parameters here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/scheduler/latest/APIReference/API_CreateSchedule.html), and on [schedule expressions here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/scheduler/latest/UserGuide/schedule-types.html#one-time).